# I/O addressing inside a computer running Windows 10

Tags: cpu, port

When I reboot my Windows 10 systems, I noticed the I/O port addresses do not change, they remain the same. For example, when viewing from Windows 10 Device Manager/View/Resource by type, I noticed the following I/O address stays the same after rebooting my system:

[image]

How is this possible? Are I/O addresses hardware on the computer motherboard? Who reads these I/O addresses?

Comment: *"How is this possible?"* -- Why are you surprised? Why do you assume that they should change?  Maybe you really don't understand what an address is?  *"Are I/O addresses hardware on the computer motherboard?"* -- They could be.  On old HW adapter boards, the address(es) was/were set with jumpers or switches.  But modern HW, e.g. PCI, uses soft configuration.  *"Who reads these I/O addresses?"* -- The address decoder.

Comment: Even on older I/O cards that one could change the address, you could only choose from a specific set of addresses. This is because the computer expects certain functions to be accessible via ports found at hard coded addresses. Modems and their configurable COM port is a good example.